# jQuery droppable not working on absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that divided into 6 grids. Those grids are using absolute positioning for placement.

For some reason jQuery droppable not working on those absolute divs.

Can some tell me whats wrong with my code?

I created a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r8amtdjs/) to show you my current code.

This is the jQuery part.

```
$(".ui-draggable").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit',
        stack: '.ui-draggable',
        revert: "invalid"
    });

    $(".ui-droppable").droppable({
        accept: ".ui-draggable"
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

it seems to be working fine, try this

```
$(".ui-draggable").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit',
    stack: '.ui-draggable',
    revert: "invalid"
});

$(".ui-droppable").droppable({
   accept: ".ui-draggable",
   drop: function( event, ui ) {
      alert('dropped');
   }
});
```

You'll see that the drop event fires correctly

Are you expecting some extra behavior?

if you want the picture to stay where you drop it, use

```
$(".ui-draggable").draggable({
     stack: '.ui-draggable',
     revert: "invalid"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code. But is there a way I can make it to fit inside grid? As of now it stays in any position after I drag it. http://jsfiddle.net/r8amtdjs/2/